# Django - Add block inside an included html

Tags: html, django, templates, webserver

In Django, can we add block content in a included html page? Is it feasible?

**base.html**

```
{% block title %}
    <p>This is title base.html</p>
{% endblock title %}

{% include "head.html" %}
```

**head.html**

```
{% block subtitle %}
    <p>This is subtitle head.html</p>
{% endblock subtitle %}
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
    <p>This is title index.html</p>
{% endblock title %}


{% block subtitle %}
    <p>This is subtitle index.html</p>
{% endblock subtitle %}
```

**Final result**

```html
<p>This is title dashboard.html</p>
<p>This is subtitle head.html</p>
```

Meaning, that when we are rendering index.html, it will not find the subtitle block on head.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#include):

> The **include** tag should be considered as an implementation of
> “render this subtemplate and include the HTML”, not as “parse this
> subtemplate and include its contents as if it were part of the
> parent”. This means that there is no shared state between included
> templates – each include is a completely independent rendering
> process.
>
> Blocks are evaluated before they are included. This means that a
> template that includes blocks from another will contain blocks that
> have *already been evaluated and rendered* - not blocks that can be
> overridden by, for example, an extending template.

In simpler words as you notice, what you try is not possible.

How to overcome this? Simply bring the blocks to the parent template:

**base.html**

```
{% block title %}
    <p>This is title base.html</p>
{% endblock title %}
{% block subtitle %}
    {% include "head.html" %}
{% endblock subtitle %}
```

**head.html**

```
<p>This is subtitle head.html</p>
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
    <p>This is title index.html</p>
{% endblock title %}


{% block subtitle %}
    <p>This is subtitle index.html</p>
{% endblock subtitle %}
```